# Can't compile a file with SDL library linked on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linker, sdl

We have an assignment to compile a file with SDL library linked. The file itself shouldn't contain any errors since almost everyone managed to compile it. I've installed SDL 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev 
sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev 
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

I'm compiling it with the following command:

```
gcc -o sdl_introduction  sdl_introduction.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

I'm using with gcc 4.6.3
and I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libSDL.so: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to compile with specifying the libraries directly? Does that give the same errors? gcc -o sdl_introduction  sdl_introduction.c -lSDL -l SDL_main -lGL

Comment: @Jan if i do it that way it gives me another error: `sdl_introduction.c:16:20: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: Strange. Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the same problem as you, it is caused by the SDL library needing other libraries to link with on ubuntu(or linux generally)

I recommend copiling it with :

```
gcc -o sdl_introduction  sdl_introduction.c -lX11 -pthread `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

Notice the added -lX11 and -pthread.

EDIT:

My bad I forgot that you must add -lX11 and -pthread after the other flags.
Resulting in:

```
gcc -o sdl_introduction  sdl_introduction.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -lX11 -pthread
```

Comment: apparently it has something to do with x11 library. if i try to run X11 in terminal it shows that it is not installed but when i try to install it it gives me the following message: `x11-common is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  blender-codecs-ffmpeg1.2 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libopenimageio1.1
  libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 thunderbird-globalmenu libcmis-0.2-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

Comment: `XGetRequest()` is part of X11 not part of SDL. SDL just needs it. You need to also install the X11 developer files. Do something like `apt-get install x11-dev`. The "*something like*" referrs to `x11-dev`.

Comment: @orustammanapov: `"x11-dev"` in my previous comment probably should be `libx11-dev`.

Comment: @alk thanks you were right i was missing x11-dev but i could only install it by typing in `xorg-dev` instead of `x11-dev` or `libx11-dev`

Comment: @alkaltar it worked but '-lX11 -pthread' should be added to the end else it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @orustammanapov I edited the answer to clarify for future readers.